# how to use Picasso with custom Adapter for RecyclerView

Tags: android, picasso

I am populating a `RecyclerView` with images that are loaded from web. I am able to load images using an `AsyncTask` inside my adapter. However, as I need to implement it with Picasso, I need a help. Here is the code so far:

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MovieViewHolder>
{
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    int pos;
    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
         CardView cv;
        TextView MovieName;
         ImageView MoviePhoto;

        MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            MovieName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
            MoviePhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_photo);
        }
    }

    List<Post> mpost;

    CustomAdapter(List<Post> mpost){
        this.mpost = mpost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        MovieViewHolder pvh = new MovieViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder movieViewHolder, int i)
    {
        pos=i;
        movieViewHolder.MovieName.setText(mpost.get(i).getTitle());

        if(mpost.get(pos).getPoster_path()!=null)
        {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154"+mpost.get(pos).getPoster_path());
                        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();




            movieViewHolder.MoviePhoto.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

        }




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        if(mpost!=null)
        {
            return mpost.size();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

And I need to replace this :

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154"+mpost.get(pos).getPoster_path());
                    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();




        movieViewHolder.MoviePhoto.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

with picasso:

```
Picasso.with(this)
                .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154" + mpost.get(pos).getPoster_path())
                .into(MoviePhoto);
```

However, there seems to be error ddoing so, whats the best fix?

Comment: ...plz check my solution...and let me know if there is any concern

Comment: you cannot use `Picasso.with(this)` you need to pass your activity's context to the adapter and use that as `Picasso.with(mContext)`..you could pass activity context using adapter constructor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Picasso as following code in the `onBindViewHolder` method the `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder movieViewHolder, int position){


    Post model = mpost.get(position);    

    movieViewHolder.MovieName.setText(model.getTitle());
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154" + model.getPoster_path()).into(movieViewHolder.MoviePhoto)

}
```

Comment: thanks, cannot resolve symbol `getContext()`  , whats the reason? :/

Comment: In place of getContex() you can put your activity name like "MY_ACYIVITY.THIS"

Comment: The only problem i had in the posted problem was with context, it does not fix that

Comment: Use an instance of your activity context instead `getContext()`, pass it by  `CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Post> mpost)` or use `movieViewHolder.MovieName.getContext()`

Comment: Yes, in fact I've edited the answer a bit, so that it ll help someone in future! :)

Comment: @oblivion ...Happy to help bro... :)

Comment: I can't see any reason to use a custom target instead of 
.into(MoviePhoto);

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder movieViewHolder, int i){
    pos=i;
    movieViewHolder.MovieName.setText(mpost.get(i).getTitle());
    if(mpost.get(pos).getPoster_path()!=null){
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154" + mpost.get(pos).getPoster_path()).into(movieViewHolder.MoviePhoto)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MovieViewHolder>
{
Bitmap mBitmap;
int pos;
Context context;
public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
     CardView cv;
    TextView MovieName;
     ImageView MoviePhoto;

    MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        MovieName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
        MoviePhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_photo);
    }
}

List<Post> mpost;

CustomAdapter(Context context,List<Post> mpost){
    this.mpost = mpost;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    MovieViewHolder pvh = new MovieViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder movieViewHolder, int i)
{
    pos=i;
    movieViewHolder.MovieName.setText(mpost.get(i).getTitle());

    if(mpost.get(pos).getPoster_path()!=null)
    {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154"+mpost.get(pos).getPoster_path());
                    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();




        movieViewHolder.MoviePhoto.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

    }




}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    if(mpost!=null)
    {
        return mpost.size();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

}
```

Use this code and pass context of activity in CustomAdapter.

```
CustomAdater customAdapter= new CustomAdapter(this,post);
```

use context instead of this with your picasso code.

Answer (score 0):

In method onBindViewHolder set the piccaso for loading an image to image view

```
onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder movieViewHolder, int position)
Picasso.with(context)
            .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154" + mpost.get(position).getPoster_path())
            .into(movieViewHolder.MoviePhoto);`
```

As simple as that. :)